# Retrieve List of Log4J Appenders at Run Time

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is it possible to retrieve a list of all appenders configured in log4j at run time?

I'll flesh out the scenario a little more.  Given the following config how would I retrieve all appenders (stdout and altstdout)?

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.altstdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.altstdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.altstdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: are you using lo4j 1.2 or log4j2 ? Tagging both is confusing as they have different APIs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want access to all appenders configured for all loggers you must do something like this

```
for (Enumeration loggers=LogManager.getCurrentLoggers(); loggers.hasMoreElements(); )  {
    Logger logger = (Logger) loggers.nextElement();
    for (Enumeration appenders=logger.getAllAppenders(); appenders.hasMoreElements(); )  {
        Appender appender = (Appender) appenders.nextElement();
        ...
```

I don't know why log4j has no method like LogManager.getAllAppenders(), but it looks like
disadvantage.

Comment: That would work, but it wasn't really relevant for our need.  I was creating a logging config app so we could dynamically create/modify loggers.  This basically required appenders that weren't currently in use.  In the end I just created a logger that was configured with all appenders and was always set to OFF.

Comment: This may work for log4j but definitively not for log4j2, because in log4j2 there is no LogManager.getCurrentLoggers() neither Logger.getAllAppenders().

Comment: so how do you do this in log4j2

Comment: what is LogManager?

Answer (score 0):

This is one what you need

[log4j Method getAllAppenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#getAllAppenders%28%29)

Comment: This just gets all appenders attached to a logger doesn't it?

Comment: Don't recommend this at all.  From the documentation for the class: "This class has been deprecated and replaced by the Logger subclass. It will be kept around to preserve backward compatibility until mid 2003. "

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something that took me a while to understand.
If you look at the figure below (which I copied from [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)), you can see, that even though the logger `com.foo.bar` will print to the root loggers FileAppender, its appender list is still null. So you cannot get all appenders the logger will write to with the method `logger.getAllAppenders()`.

[image]

For this you need to iterate through all the parents also and the root logger seperately. Because you cannot iterate `logger.getParent()` to root logger (root logger returns null - see documentation of getParent()). As far as I know, you have to access the rootLoggers' appenders seperately via `Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders().`

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution for Log4j 1:

Note: getAllAppenders will get only active log. Not the full list of files defined in your log4j.xml configuration file.

Here's how I could achieve this for setting rwxrwxrwx rights on all log files

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E> E safeCastNoException(Object o, Class<E> target)
{
  if(target.isInstance(o)) return (E)o;
  return null;
}
    {

        URL file;
        try
        {
            LogManager.resetConfiguration();
            file = new URL("file:" + Log4jXMLConfigFileName);
            // We override DOMConfigurator to catch Appender settings
            // in parseAppender and rework file rights access
            new DOMConfigurator()
            {
                @Override
                protected Appender parseAppender(Element appenderElement)
                {
                    Appender a = super.parseAppender(appenderElement);

                    FileAppender fileAppender = safeCastNoException(a, FileAppender.class);
                    if( fileAppender != null )
                    {
                        String filePath=fileAppender.getFile();

                        Path pathTofile = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
                        try
                        {
                            // Create the empty file with default permissions, etc.
                            Files.createFile(pathTofile);
                        }
                        catch(FileAlreadyExistsException x)
                        {
                            System.err.format("file named %s already exists, no need to recreate%n", pathTofile);
                        }
                        catch(Exception x)
                        {
                            // Some other sort of failure, such as permissions.
                            System.err.format("createFile error: %s%n", x);
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            //using PosixFilePermission to set file permissions 777
                            Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
                            //add owners permission
                            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
                            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
                            //perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
                            //add group permissions
                            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
                            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
                            //perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
                            //add others permissions
                            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
                            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
                            //perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);
                            System.out.println("Trying to set 666 posix rights to log file: " + pathTofile.toAbsolutePath().toString());
                            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get(pathTofile.toAbsolutePath().toString()), perms);
                        }
                        catch(Exception x)
                        {
                            // Some other sort of failure, such as permissions.
                            System.err.format("chmod error: %s%n", x);
                        }
                    }
                    return a;
                }
            }.
            doConfigure(file, LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```