# Not seeing any java logging after creating an object

Tags: java, logging, stderr

I am extending functionality of a Java project that I inherited that has logging implemented using a class `Log` that wraps `java.util.logging.Logger`:

```
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Log {

    // ...
    private final Logger log;
```

I am integrating a third-party library and the problem I've run into is that after I create an object of a class from this library, all logging stops. Or, more precisely, I don't see any log messages in `System.err`. So in the block below that creates an object of class `SomeClass`:

```
public class TopClass {

    private static final Log log = new Log(TopClass.class);

    // ...

    private static SomeClass foo = null;

    // ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ...
        log.severe("SEVERE-BEFORE");
        log.info("INFO-BEFORE");
        foo = new SomeClass();
        log.severe("SEVERE-AFTER");
        log.info("INFO-AFTER");
```

I can see `SEVERE-BEFORE` and `INFO-BEFORE` but not `SEVERE-AFTER` or `INFO-AFTER`.

How do I figure out what happens with logging during `foo`'s initialization? I have access to some of the source code of the `SomeClass` library and I searched for any mentions of "log" but did not find any. The library does have a few `System.err.priteln()` calls. The library also depends on a couple of other libs whose source I don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the constructor `SomeClass` of throws an exception.
Try to wrap your code in `try-catch`.

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ...
        log.severe("SEVERE-BEFORE");
        log.info("INFO-BEFORE");
        try
        {
            foo = new SomeClass();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            log.severe("an exception was thrown", t);
        }
        log.severe("SEVERE-AFTER");
        log.info("INFO-AFTER");
```

Comment: No, the instantiation works fine. There is a lot more code past the `log.info("INFO-AFTER");` point it's just none of `log.info()` or `log.severe()` etc produce any output in `System.err`

Comment: Interesting. How about trying using something along the answer to this question:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024733/retrieve-list-of-log4j-appenders-at-run-time  
and print all appenders before and after the instantiation?

Comment: I am not using log4j in my project yet but I might switch to it, maybe the problem will go away...

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact you're using `java.util.logging.Logger`.  
in that case, you could try the same with `getHandlers()`