# Ways to configure logs other than log4j xml, properties file, and source code (mainly java)?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I'm looking at the source code of some application. It is using **Spring framework, Apache Tiles, JSP, Log4j, java, javascript, jquery, jqplot, Jsch**, and etc.

I know where the logs are created. (a/b/logs) However, when I look at source code, I don't know how logs are created under the folder name 'logs'.  I looked at log4j.xml,  web.xml , property files. I found the code for how the path 'a/b' is created, but not logs. Also that folder has 4 types of logs. And they are name in a pattern like  access.20181227001 , errors.20182111.  I want to know where I have to look to find how the logs are created in this manner.

> ***Log4J.xml***

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p [%c] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="console-infolog" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p %m%n" />
    </layout>  
</appender> 

<!-- Application Loggers -->
<logger name="com.dsmentoring.chakan" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</logger>

<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.core">
    <level value="error"/> 
</logger>

<!-- Bean logger -->
<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="error"/> 
</logger>

<!-- Context logger -->
<logger name="org.springframework.context">
    <level value="error"/> 
</logger>

<!-- Web logger -->
<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="error"/> 
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.ldap" additivity="true">
    <level value="error"/> 
</logger>
<!-- LDAP logger -->
<logger name="com.unboundid.ldap" additivity="true">
    <level value="error"/> 
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="off" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

To sum up :

1)  Is there a way to configure where logs are created and how they are created (4 types of logs) Other than log4j.xml, xml files and property files?  I looked at all the java, jsp, js code but can't seem to find the configuration for logs. So I want to know if there are other ways to do that or where I should look for those configuration.

2) The 'logs' folder is possibly default for log4j?

> **ldap.properties**

```
#LDAP Connection Info
ldap.host=192.168.0.17 
ldap.port=22389 
ldap.userName=cn=directory manager 
ldap.password= 9074B18A0DE2D50C068D37B60BE5DFDE 
ldap.baseDN=o=sso30root 
ldap.defaultLoadSize=1000 
ldap.start=start-ds 
ldap.stop=stop-ds 
ldap.workdir=/home/KB_openDJ     // logs are created under this path
                                 // /home/KB_openDJ/logs
```

In other java class, they use this.

```
@Value("${ldap.workdir}")
private String WORK_DIR;

//  I ommited many lines in between

try{
            diskUsage = sigar.getFileSystemUsage(WORK_DIR);
            diskIOInfo.setDiskRead((int)(diskUsage.getDiskReadBytes()));
            diskIOInfo.setDiskWrite((int)(diskUsage.getDiskWriteBytes()));
        }catch(SigarException sigarEx){
            log.debug("Disk Usage info load Error : " + sigarEx.getMessage());
        }
```

I used the 'Search' feature in Eclipse many times. ( logs, WORK_DIR, and 4 types of log name, and many others. I am unable to locate the code about logging configuration. :(

**My log4j version** :

> 1.2.15

Comment: Actually log4j appenders might be created programatically. What is obvious: your xml configuration file doesn't declary any file appender. Try to find usages of `Appender` interface in your code.

Comment: @Laplas  I've searched the whole workspace in Eclipse with the "Appender", but nothing. :(   Just appenders in log4j.xml.  Do you happen to have any thoughts on how 4 types of logs are created?   Usually they are done with codes? or xml or properties files?

Comment: From my experience logging framework is usually configured in xml files. Can you please show us an excerpt of code where _the path 'a/b' is created_?

Comment: @Laplas okay~ hold on. Let me edit my question

Comment: Jin Lee, please provide info about log4j version used. I'll try to dive into log4j configuration order. It turns out that there are extremly lots of ways to specify configuration of log4j [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: @Laplas  hey thanks for all the trouble.  My jar says 'log4j-1.2.15.jar' .  Also in log4j.xml  something says ' //APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN"  "log4j.dtd" '   so my log4j version is 1.2.15.  I also found out that it is possible to configure logs with javascripts and jquery, so I'm going to go through all the js one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that there's a solution which might help you. It requires some debugging of static initalization block of `org.apache.log4j.LogManager` class. This class is responsible for loading logger configuration file. Here's a documention link which thoroughly describes initalization process: [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit).
Here's an excerpt from a LogManager source file:

```
String configurationOptionStr = OptionConverter.getSystemProperty(DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_KEY, null);
String configuratorClassName = OptionConverter.getSystemProperty(CONFIGURATOR_CLASS_KEY, null);
```

What I'm trying to show you here, is that your logger configuration file might be specified as a JVM option supplied to your application-server. That's why you are not able to determine actual file being used.

Even if this approach fails, I'd recommend you to investigate the appenders list retrieved at run-time. Here's a stackoverflow thread which describes how to do so: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024733/retrieve-list-of-log4j-appenders-at-run-time).